# Why do I have to use .copy only for List when I want to create another copy for list but not for Integer in python?

Tags: python

When I do A=B for Integers and change value of B later A retains its original value but for list I have to do A=B.copy() or else both list would change why is this the case when both are objects?

Comment: Read and understand [Python Names and Values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html).

Comment: When you change the list named by `A` you are *not* changing the value of the name `A` but are instead mutating the mutable object that `A` happens to name (which is the same mutable object that `B` happens to name after running the line `A=B`).

Comment: @jarmod Thanks alot that link really helped me alot

Comment: @ShaSha-Codes glad it helped. It's a real eye-opener for people coming from other languages when they first use Python. Many Python programmers never understand these fundamentals but it's critical groundwork for truly understanding Python.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `A` and `B` aren't actually lists. They are pointers to lists. When you say `A=B` you are making `A` point to the place `B` points to. Why do this? Because Python doesn't know how long your list will be, which means if the list grows it might not fit in that place in memory anymore. So it is more efficient just to identify the location where the list starts.

This is the same for objects and dicts in Python.

Where might you see this bug? Well, if you are referencing an object which might change, make a copy of it. Here is a simplified example of how this could happen when doing machine learning:

```py
# hypothetical list storing training history
logs = []
for i in range(10):
    model.train(data)

    # error! model.parameters is a pointer!
    logs.append(model.parameters)

# each item in this list will be the same!
print(logs)
```

Comment: The example went a little over my head but I got the concept Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

Let us go slowly and find out why this happens.
`>>> a=5`
`>>> b=5`
`>>> print(id(a),id(b))`
Output:
`(1692102715824,1692102715824)`
As we can see both `a` and `b` are pointing to `5` stored in the same memory location `1692102715824`.Now, if we change the value of `b` to `6` then,
`>>> b=6`
`>>> print(id(a),id(b))`
Output:
`(1692102715824,1692102715856)`
So now you see that the variable `a` is pointing to a different memory location, and `b` is pointing to a different location. So that's how `a` retains it's original value, because we are not changing the value stored in `a` and `b`, but what python does is, it points `b` to where `6` is stored in the memory.
Now coming to lists.
`>>> list1=[1,2,3]`
`>>> list2=list1`
`>>> print(id(list1),id(list2))`
Output:
`(1692143888192,1692143888192)`
When creating an empty list, python automatically chooses a ***contiguous row of memory locations*** to store the values that will eventually come into it. When two different lists say `list1` and `list2` are pointing to the same contiguous memory locations,*keep in mind that just because they have different variable names doesn't mean they point to different location*,if you check `id(list1)` and `id(list2)`, they will return the same id, so then ***any change*** in that memory location will ***affect both lists***, as here, python doesn't change the pointer to another memory location, but changes the values in the same spot.Since both lists are pointing to the same spot, so both lists reflect the same changes. 
So it is advised to used `copy()`, because when `copy()` is used, python creates another contiguous memory location for your second list, such that any changes in any of the two separate lists, will not affect each other.
Comment down below if you need more clarifications. Please refrain from thanking in the comments.

Comment: It seems inaccurate to speak of *different* lists when they share the same `id()`. Thinking of them as different lists just because there are different names is the core confusion, which your answer doesn't really clarify.

Comment: @JohnColeman I have edited the explanation as per your comment. Hopefully it is now a complete answer.